# Creating player object not working from constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor

Need some expertise on this one. I am currently Spawning a player from a class in a way where I create the object and then define the variables line by line, like this:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.Avatar = go;
p.PlayerName = playerName;
p.ConnectionId = cnnId;
p.Avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = pName;
players.Add(cnnId, p);
```

and the player class was a simple little bit structured like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public GameObject Avatar;
    public int ConnectionId;
}
```

So that worked, but I wanted to expand the arguments and use a constructor to create my player object which I tried to do by creating my object like this instead:

`Player p = new Player(playerName, go, cnnId);
 p.Avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = pName;
 players.Add(cnnId, p);`

and then I created my constructor like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public struct Player {

    Client client;

    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public GameObject Avatar { get; set; }
    public int ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Tex { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Hitpoints { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }

    // Initial method takes base arguments for testing
    public Player(string playerName, GameObject avatar, int connectionID) : this()
    {
        this.PlayerName = playerName;
        this.Avatar = avatar;
        this.ConnectionId = connectionID;

        client.infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += playerName + " " + ConnectionId + " " + "\n";
    }

    // Overload method takes all player arguments
    public Player(string playerName, GameObject avatar, int connectionID, byte[] tex, string type, string id, int strength, int hitpoints, bool isAlive) : this()
    {
        this.PlayerName = playerName;
        this.Avatar = avatar;
        this.ConnectionId = connectionID;

        this.Tex = tex;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Strength = strength;
        this.Hitpoints = hitpoints;
        this.IsAlive = isAlive;

        Debug.Log(id + " : " + type + " created with strength " + strength + ", hit points " + hitpoints + ", and a texture the size of " + tex.Length);

        client.infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += playerName + " " + id + " : " + type + " created with strength " + strength + ", hit points " + hitpoints + ", and a texture the size of " + tex.Length +" \n";
    }
}
```

When I try to use the constructor method though it doesn't work - my player name doesn't appear and my player movement doesn't get updated across the network anymore. What changes do I need to make to get my constructor to work?

Complete function that I'm using to Spawn my player:

```
private void SpawnPlayer(string pName, int cnnId)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(playerPrefab) as GameObject;

        // Is this our player?
        if (cnnId == ourClientId)
        {
            // Add mobility
            go.AddComponent<Movement>();    // Add Movement.cs Script

            // Remove Connect Button
            if(GameObject.Find("Canvas").activeInHierarchy == true)
                GameObject.Find("ConnectButton").SetActive(false);

            isStarted = true;
        }

        Player p = new Player(playerName, go, cnnId);
        p.Avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = pName;
        players.Add(cnnId, p);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a struct at all? if you switch to a class does it fix your problems?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not getting any NullReferenceException, especially when setting the avatar GameObject?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain switching to a class doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to use the constructor method though it doesn't work - my
>   player name doesn't appear and my player movement doesn't get updated
>   across the network anymore. What changes do I need to make to get my
>   constructor to work?

First of all, this doesn't have anything to so with the constructor. Notice that your working `Player` is a `struct` and the none working one is a `class`. This really shouldn't make any difference.

Here are two possible reasons why your new class is not being updated:

**1**.The problem is the use of `{ get; set; }` in that class. Unity cannot serialize/de-serialize auto property. Remove them from each variable in that `class` and it should work.

**2**.Also, you are not initializing the `client` variable in that class. Initialize it before using it or performing `client.infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>()` on it.

Comment: Removing { get; set; } didn't fix the issue unfortunately. I posted the entire function that I'm using to spawn my player objects above. Is there something else in the there that I have wrong perhaps?

Comment: Please read the second part of my answer abut using a variable that you did not initialize....

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. I initialized the variable, everything is working. Thank you!